# How do I get a set difference between 2 observables?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've got `obs1 = Observable.range(1, 10)` and then `obs2 = Observable.range(5, 10)` (generally the sequence won't be in increasing order).

I want to get **a set difference between obs2 and obs1** to get the values (observable of them) from obs2 that aren't in obs1.

Comment: Your question and explanation reads ambiguous to me. So you want all items from obs1 and the non-duplicates from obs2? Or do you want only those items from obs2 which are not in obs1?

Comment: I want only those items from obs2 which are not in obs1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect up items from `obs1` into a `HashSet` and then filter `obs2` via `set::contains`:

```
obs1.collect(HashSet::new, (a, b) -> a.add(b))
.flatMapObservable(set -> 
    obs2.filter(set::contains)
)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way I can avoid collections for this? I'd like to be able to execute this code in multiple threads (and I don't really want to use ConcurrentHashSet cause I want to avoid blocking operations).

Comment: Yes, you have to `flatMap` `obs1` over and over for each item in `obs2`, that is an O(N*M) operations whereas this HashSet version is ~ O(N + M). With `collect` every subscriber receives a private collection and multiple realizations of the flow don't share anything with each other, therefore, `ConcurrentHashSet` is not required.

Comment: @akarnokd is correct. The idea behind the flatmap is that it creates new observables each time which are independent. You can then run operations on these independent observables concurrently.